# Testing Preferences DataStore with Mockito

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, android-testing

Good afternoon friends!

I have a DataSource with DataStore (code below).
I don't know how to properly write a test for the isWizardComplete() method, stateFlow == null. How do I initialize stateFlow and write the test correctly? I will be grateful for any help.

```
class InfoWizardDataSourceImpl(
    private val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>
) : InfoWizardDataSource {

    private val stateFlow: Flow<Boolean> = dataStore.data
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[IS_WIZARD_COMPLETE] ?: false
        }

    .......

    override suspend fun isWizardComplete(): Boolean {
        return stateFlow.first()
    }

    .......
}




class InfoWizardDataSourceImplTest : BaseCoroutinesTest() {

    private val dataStore = mock(DataStore::class.java) as DataStore<Preferences>
    private val infoWizardDataSourceImpl = InfoWizardDataSourceImpl(dataStore)
    private val IS_WIZARD_COMPLETE = booleanPreferencesKey("isWizardComplete")


    @Test
    fun isWizardComplete() {
        runCoroutineTest {
           `when`(dataStore.data.map { it[IS_WIZARD_COMPLETE] }).thenReturn(flowOf(true))
            val result = infoWizardDataSourceImpl.isWizardComplete()
            assertTrue(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock `dataStore.data`, use this code:

```
val key = booleanPreferencesKey("isWizardComplete")
Mockito.`when`(dataStore.data).thenReturn(
    flowOf(
        preferencesOf(
            key to true
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: how to mock with many key?

Comment: @BULLA like this:

`val key1 = booleanPreferencesKey("key1")
val key2 = booleanPreferencesKey("key2")
Mockito.when(dataStore.data).thenReturn(
    flowOf(
        preferencesOf(
            key to true,
            key2 to false
        )
    )
)`